# how to change a specific line in the linux command

Tags: shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

how do i change this text for a specific line

Suppose I want to change line 50, and I want to change 8 letters after **"user":**
like the example below which I bold

line 50      "user": "**9077c266**-8944-11eb-a9d1-fa163e4be1a2"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `s` command in `sed` to search and replace.

```
sed -i 'Ns/9077c266/replacement-line/' file.txt
```

where `N` should be replaced by your target line number.

To save the changed text in a different file, drop the -i option:

```
sed  'Ns/9077c266/replacement-line/' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would used sed either by line number or just content if it's unique:

```
sed -i '50s/9077c266/replacement/' file.txt
```

or:

```
sed -i 's/9077c266/replacement/' file.txt
```